# Add items and value of the drop down list from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I used this c# code to add items in `dropdownlist(ddlSub)` from the table `sub_info`. But what I want is to add the value of the items in `dropdownlist(ddlSub)` from the same table which also has a column named `sub_id` of datatype `varchar(50)`.

```
private void bind_ddlSub()
{

    ddlSub.Items.Insert(0, "-Choose-");
    datatable_object = methodClassFunc.getData("select sub_name from sub_info");
    for (int i = 0; i <= datatable_object.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        ddlSub.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(datatable_object.Rows[i]["sub_name"]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Something wrong in submitting answer, 500 error, but you can bind your drop down list with your `DataTable` and then specify DataTextField and DataValueField

Comment: private void LoadCourse()
    {
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sasdbConnectionString);
    string query = "SELECT CourseId,CourseName FROM Courses";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
    conn.Open();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Course");
    courseComboBox.DisplayMember =  "CourseName";
    courseComboBox.ValueMember = "CourseId";
    courseComboBox.DataSource = ds.Tables["Course"];
    }

Comment: yeah posting answers seems to be down right now... i can't post any answer to any question :(

Comment: @Habib thnx for ur valuable answer but wud u plz check my coding again.

Comment: @user3323819, I have posted an answer with multiple options. One to use overload constructor of `ListItem` which expects text and value and other using data binding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ListItem` object to add text and value for a dropdownlist item.

```
string subname = datatable_object.Rows[i]["sub_name"];
string subid = datatable_object.Rows[i]["sub_id"];
ddlSub.Items.Add(new ListItem(subname,subid));
```

Or you can bind your datasource like this:

```
ddlSub.DataSource = datatable_object;
ddlSub.DataTextField = "sub_name";
ddlSub.DataValueField = "sub_id";
ddlSub.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= datatable_object.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    ddlSub.Items.Add(new ListItem(Convert.ToString(datatable_object.Rows[i]["sub_name"]), 
                                  Convert.ToString(datatable_object.Rows[i]["sub_id"]));
}
```

Or you can bind the `DataTable` to your `DropDownList` and the specify [`DataTextField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for display and [`DataValueField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the value on index changed event like:

```
ddlSub.DataSource = datatable_object; 
ddlSub.DataTextField = "sub_name";
ddlSub.DataValueField = "sub_id"; 
ddlSub.DataBind();
```

Comment: wish i could be able to help you out in something, but unfortunately u r much betr than me. thank you very much from the bottom of my heart